# How to find the Direct Discrete Laplace Transform of ${2n \choose n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, laplace-transform

Some time ago I developed a discrete version of the Laplace transform for the purpose of calculating sums and solve finite difference equations with constant coefficients. The notes below are a summary of a study that I did some time. These notes on [discrete Laplace transforms](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw7gAXHqCTeodFE3anJEUm11dzA/edit?usp=sharing) are incomplete. Briefly, we have

Give the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, the discret direct Laplace transform (DDLT) denoted by $\ell_d\{x_n\}$ is defined for $s > 0$ by
$$
\ell_d\{x_n\} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}e^{-sn}x_n : = X(s)
$$
Question: I have trouble finding
$$
\ell_d\biggl\{{2n \choose n}\biggr\} 
$$
Thanks for any help and other ideas that can expand the theory.

Comment: If you write $z=e^{-s}$ then $X(z)$ is just generating function with coefficients $x_n$. And in that case you can just recognize the sum you're computing as a binomial series in $z$...

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4e^{-s}}}$$

Comment: And there it is. I think you're at risk of reinventing the wheel this way, to tell the truth: the generating function approach more or less _is_ the analogue of Laplace transforms for recurrence relations. -@blue

Comment: It's true. Had not thought about

Answer (score 1):

The generating function of Catalan's numbers $y_n=\frac 1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ is $$\sum_{n\geqslant 0 }\frac1 {n+1}\binom{2n}nx^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$$

Multplying by $x$ and differentitating gives that $$\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\binom {2n}nx^n=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$$

One can also try to prove this directly, by noting that $$\binom{-1/2}k=(-1)^k4^{-k}\binom{2k}k$$ and that $$(1+x)^{\alpha}=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\binom{\alpha}n x^n$$At any rate, any claim begs for a proof.

Comment: How to prove that the generating function of Catalan's numbers? Some reference?

Comment: Yes. You can use Google. I promise you'll find references.

Comment: Is't limited to $\displaystyle\large{\rm e}^{-s} < 1/4\ ?$.